# How to handle Authentication pop up in Safari using Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safari

I have been having issues with Safari 11 using WebDriver. I was able to bypass that authentication popup by using the following:

```
String URL = "http://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + Settings.AUT;
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL + "/");
```

This somehow worked with Safari 10, though I upgraded my Safari to 11 due to the maximize window is not working with Safari 10.
I am currently using webdriver 2.48 for safari.
I have no idea anymore on what to do with Safari tests. Is this a known issue? I know there is AutoIT but is there any other way to do this?

Comment: were you able to solve this? I too am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Ptrkcon not yet. I am watching this issue https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/385

Comment: @Marj were you able to find any solution

Comment: @RiteshKarwa this issue has been here for years, but honestly I found out that our security had like 3 layers and I couldn't do this anymore. My web dev team has been moved to another team called mobile app team which is where I now belong to. Thanks everyone for help!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your current web driver doesn't work with that version of browser.

> SafariDriver - DEPRECATED - use Apple's SafariDriver with Safari 10+
>
> SafariDriver now requires manual installation of the extension prior
> to automation

From:

http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: I am using Selenium 3.6.0. So this means I have to go back to 2.48 to have this corrected :(

Comment: I do not think it is about version of Selenium, but about web driver version.

Comment: I have used the 2.48 and manually installed in my Safari. but it is still doing the same thing

Comment: Because it has nothing to do with the version of Selenium, like I said, but with the driver in particular. I have no experience with Selenium and Safari, can't help you more, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

According to the RFC 3986 this format of passing the user name and password in the URL is deprecated and while it still works in Chrome and FF, Safari does not support this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppleScript and Java to handle the browser pop-up. Here is the Java code to execute AppleScript, just call this function and pass the AppleScript as String:

```
public static void execute(String appleScript)
{
    Process process = null;

    try
    {
        String[] args = { "osascript", "-e", appleScript };

        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

        String logs = null;

        while ((logs = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(logs);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if (process != null)
            process.destroy();
    }
}
```

If you don't know how to write AppleScript go to their tutorials.

Also, to check you have given access permission to System Events; go to 'System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility' and make sure you have 'Eclipse' and 'System Events' checked.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the applescript you used?

Comment: @RiteshKarwa For AppleScript, it doesn't matter which browser/version are you using.

Comment: I tried it with safari and  web-driver is not letting Applescript interact with the browser

Comment: @RiteshKarwa That might be your system configuration/access permission issue. To make sure it's not the case. Follow the steps: Go to 'System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility' and make sure you have 'Eclipse' and 'System Events' checked.

Comment: I think it is the glass pane, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/about_webdriver_for_safari. It is preventing the Apple Script from interacting with the browser